# I am using C# to design a calcuator and i get Complie Error CS0029

Tags: c#, button, compiler-errors, calculator

So for my homework I am asked to design a fully functioning calcuator that accepts both key presses and button clicks but for the numbers 0-9 button clicks events I get Compile Error Message: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

here is the code

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Calculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private String calculatedNumber;     // Stores numbers in string form
        private Boolean dot = false;         // Falg: to control when a dot can be placed in a number
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnZero_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //adds 0 to string
        {
            //calculatedNumber = Convert.ToString(0);
            if (calculatedNumber = 0)
            {

                LblDisplay.Text=calculatedNumber;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        private void BtnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   //adds 1 to string
        {

            if (calculatedNumber = 1)
            {
                calculatedNumber = 1.ToString();
                LblDisplay.Text = calculatedNumber;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        private void BtnTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   //adds 2 to string
        {

            if (calculatedNumber = 2)
            {
                LblDisplay.Text = calculatedNumber;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        private void BtnThree_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   //adds 3 to string
        {

            if (calculatedNumber = 3)
            {
                LblDisplay.Text = calculatedNumber;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        private void BtnFour_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   //adds 4 to string
        {

            if (calculatedNumber = 4)
            {
                LblDisplay.Text = calculatedNumber;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   //adds 5 to string
        {

            if (calculatedNumber = 5)
            {
                LblDisplay.Text = calculatedNumber;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        private void BtnSix_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   //adds 6 to string
        {

            if (calculatedNumber = 6)
            {
                LblDisplay.Text = calculatedNumber;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        private void BtnSeven_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   //adds 7 to string
        {

            if (calculatedNumber = 7)
            {
                LblDisplay.Text = calculatedNumber;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        private void BtnEight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   //adds 8 to string
        {

            if (calculatedNumber = 8)
            {
                LblDisplay.Text = calculatedNumber;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        private void BtnNine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   //adds 9 to string
        {
            calculatedNumber = 9.ToString();
            if (calculatedNumber = 9)
            {

                LblDisplay.Text = calculatedNumber;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        private void BtnDot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   //adds . to string
        {
            if (!dot)
            {
                calculatedNumber += ".";
                dot = true;
            }

            LblDisplay.Text = calculatedNumber;
        }
```

what am I doing wrong?
PS: I am new to C#

Comment: Why are you trying to store numbers into a `string`?  And if you do just do all of them the same as you do for 9.  Finally I think you want to append them instead of replacing the value.  `calculatedNumber += 9.ToString();`.  Also you can remove a lot of duplicate code by having all the buttons use the same click event and figure out which digit is added by looking at the button name.

Comment: The conditions looks wrong: `if (calculatedNumber = 2)`. First of all you use asignment instead of equality comparison. You need to use a double equality sign: `==`. Other thing, you need to compare the same types, currently there are `calculatedNumber ` which is a `string` and you compare it to integer 2. So maybe the condition should look like `if (calculatedNumber == "2")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error message "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'" from all of your `if` statements. You should be passing in an expression which returns a `bool`. However you are trying to assign an int to `calculatedNumber` which is a string. But you are meaning to check equality which is `==` not `=`.

Change all of your `if` statements to:

```
if (calculatedNumber == "0") //or whatever number
```

However in your code `calculatedNumber` never seems to be set anywhere so will never be true.

Since you have action listeners for each button the whole `if` part is redundant. You can just have:

```
 private void BtnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   //adds 1 to string
 {
      LblDisplay.Text = "1";
 }
```

However that still doesn't seem like the functionality you want as it replaces the number every time you click a new number, you probably want to append it like this:

```
private void BtnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   //adds 1 to string
{
      LblDisplay.Text = LblDisplay.Text + "1";
}
```

Comment: I used the If statements to allow the program to accept key presses is there something I can use instead